# Sending mail to an non-existent user, where should it go?

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, sendmail

When I sent a mail from the command line, where should it end up? (I want to bounce all invalid mail from outside because, spam.) Is there a way for it to give an error saying the user doesn't exist before it even asks for the subject?

```
[root@308321 postfix]# mail notthere
Subject: should bounce
hello?
EOT
```

Here is maillog

```
Oct 26 05:29:23 308321 postfix/pickup[6510]: 72F51D4775: uid=0 from=<root>
Oct 26 05:29:23 308321 postfix/cleanup[6805]: 72F51D4775: message-id=<20121026052923.72F51D4775@mail.domain.com>
Oct 26 05:29:23 308321 postfix/qmgr[6511]: 72F51D4775: from=<root@domain.com>, size=432, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 26 05:29:23 308321 postfix/virtual[6808]: 72F51D4775: to=<notthere@domain.com>, orig_to=<notthere>, relay=virtual, delay=0.74, delays=0.48/0.01/0/0.25, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "notthere@domain.com")
Oct 26 05:29:23 308321 postfix/cleanup[6805]: F277DD4776: message-id=<20121026052923.F277DD4776@mail.domain.com>
Oct 26 05:29:24 308321 postfix/qmgr[6511]: F277DD4776: from=<>, size=2225, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 26 05:29:24 308321 postfix/bounce[6809]: 72F51D4775: sender non-delivery notification: F277DD4776
Oct 26 05:29:24 308321 postfix/qmgr[6511]: 72F51D4775: removed
Oct 26 05:29:24 308321 postfix/virtual[6808]: F277DD4776: to=<root@domain.com>, relay=virtual, delay=0.56, delays=0.22/0/0/0.35, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "root@domain.com")
Oct 26 05:29:24 308321 postfix/qmgr[6511]: F277DD4776: removed
```

Comment: Using postfix and virtual users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail is rejected as soon as recipient is checked. If you really want to see exactly when the server reject it try using

`telnet server 25`

and not mail program.

http://james.apache.org/server/rfclist/smtp/rfc0821.txt
Here you can find out how to do it.

And here (http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix_restrictions) you can find in what point postfix checks for different restrictions you set.

Comment: Ok that worked. `RCPT TO:notthere@domain.com
550 5.1.1 <notthere@domain.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table`

Comment: I was able to send myself spam without authentication. How is that possible? `RCPT TO:info@domain.com
250 2.1.5 Ok
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
From:spammer@howdy.com
To:info@domain.com
Subject: Yummy spam!`

Comment: Never mind. I received ` Relay access denied;` when I tried to send to my Yahoo. But it allowed me to use non-SSL. How is that possible?

Comment: Non SSL is allowed but probably if you want to authenticate for sending messages to other domains (relaying) SSL will be enforced.